# Assign registered User to Customer Model

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-views

I want to assign a new registered User to my customer model.

At the moment user is successfully registered into the back end but is not assigning to a new Customer model, When redirected to home page after registration the following error occurs:

```
Exception Value:    
User has no customer.
```

The error is pointing to this utils model:

```
def cartData(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, order_status='P')
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        cookieData = cookieCart(request)
        cartItems = cookieData['cartItems']
        order = cookieData['order']
        items = cookieData['items']

    return {'cartItems': cartItems, 'order': order, 'items': items}
```

**Customer Model:**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

**User Register and Login Views:**

```
def UserRegister(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ("Registration successful, you are now logged in..."))
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()

    return render(request, 'authenticate/register.html', {'form': form})

   

def UserLogin(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ("You were successfully logged in..."))
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.success(request, ("There was an error logging in, please try again..."))
            return redirect('login')
       
    return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {})
```

Comment: As the error says, for the logged in user, apparently you did not make a `Customer` record.

Comment: this is what I am trying to work out, why is it not recording?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solved this issue by amending the following View:

```
def UserRegister(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
           >> first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name'] <<
            >> last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name'] <<
            >> email = form.cleaned_data['email'] <<
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            >> Customer.objects.create(user=user,first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email) <<

            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ("Registration successful, you are now logged in..."))
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()

    return render(request, 'authenticate/register.html', {'form': form})
```